# Why a function can change the values of an array and main() can see changes?

Tags: c

I'm having the following below.

When I give values to the array through the `read_data` value, then values of the array can be read by `main()` without `read_data` returning anything. Does the 
`grade_table2` array points to the same address in memory like `grade_table`?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#define NUM_STUDENTS 3
#define NUM_COURSES 2

void read_data(float grade_table2[][NUM_COURSES])
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<NUM_STUDENTS;++i)
        for(j=0;j<NUM_COURSES;++j)
            scanf("%f",&grade_table2[i][j]);
} 


int main() 
{
    float grade_table[NUM_STUDENTS][NUM_COURSES];
    float average_per_student[NUM_STUDENTS];
    float average_per_course[NUM_COURSES];
    int i,j;
    read_data(grade_table);

    for(i=0;i<NUM_STUDENTS;++i){
        for(j=0;j<NUM_COURSES;++j)
            printf("%.2f ",grade_table[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, they point to the same address.

Comment: @Rafael Thank you! In case I use a variable instead of an array, does the new variable's value passed to main() without return?

Comment: to change simple variable you should use pointers

Comment: @NickS Great, thank you! Thanks for the information! It's really useful to me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

In plain English, when you passed `grade_table` to `read_data`, you actually passed a pointer to the first element, so any updates to `grade_table2` in `read_data` are reflected in `grade_table` in `main`.

In the context of a function parameter declaration, `T a[N]` and `T a[]` are interpreted as `T *a`.  Note that this is only true for function parameters.

This "decay" rule *only* applies to array expressions.  `struct` and `union` arguments are passed by value like any scalar type (`int`, `float`, etc.).